# I need to compile libtiff4-dev on MacBook, which is the architecture?

Tags: macos, compilation

I'm in the need of compiling `libtiff4-dev` on my Mac, it's a required packages to install OCRopus.

After some searches online I've found this site that provides different version for Debian:
http://packages.debian.org/lenny/libtiff4-dev

Which one should I choose to compile on my MacBook? I have 10.5.8 version with a 2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor.